# 10170 syntax error occurs for verilog codes to on/off the 7 segment LED

Tags: syntax-error, verilog, quartus, seven-segment-display

My project is about finding the common factor value between two inputs P[3:0] and Q[3:0]. The display output is G[13:0]. P,Q and G are 2 digits values. I am trying to build a display module for two digits 7 segment display with the code below. However, the compilation is fail.

this is my code:

```
module display(
    input[3:0] p0,q0,
    output reg[13:0]LEDp,LEDq,LEDg);

    always @*
    begin
        case(p0)
            4'b0000 ： LEDp = 14'b11111111000000;
            4'b0001 ： LEDp = 14'b11111111111001;
            4'b0010 ： LEDp = 14'b11111110100100;
            4'b0011 ： LEDp = 14'b11111110110000;
            4'b0100 ： LEDp = 14'b11111110011001;
            4'b0101 ： LEDp = 14'b11111110010010;
            4'b0110 ： LEDp = 14'b11111110000010; 
            4'b0111 ： LEDp = 14'b11111111111000;
            4'b1000 ： LEDp = 14'b11111110000000;
            4'b1001 ： LEDp = 14'b11111110010000;
            4'b1010 ： LEDp = 14'b11111101000000;
            4'b1011 ： LEDp = 14'b11111101111001;
            4'b1100 ： LEDp = 14'b11111100100100;
            4'b1101 ： LEDp = 14'b11111100110000;
            4'b1110 ： LEDp = 14'b11111100011001;
            4'b1111 ： LEDp = 14'b11111100010010;
            default : LEDp = 14'b01111110111111;
        endcase
    end
        
    always @*
    begin
        case (q0)
            4'b0000： LEDq = 14'b11111111000000;
            4'b0001： LEDq = 14'b11111111111001;
            4'b0010： LEDq = 14'b11111110100100;
            4'b0011： LEDq = 14'b11111110110000;
            4'b0100： LEDq = 14'b11111110011001;
            4'b0101： LEDq = 14'b11111110010010;
            4'b0110： LEDq = 14'b11111110000010;
            4'b0111： LEDq = 14'b11111111111000;
            4'b1000： LEDq = 14'b11111110000000;
            4'b1001： LEDq = 14'b11111110010000;
            4'b1010： LEDq = 14'b11111101000000;
            4'b1011： LEDq = 14'b11111101111001;
            4'b1100： LEDq = 14'b11111100100100;
            4'b1101： LEDq = 14'b11111100110000;
            4'b1110： LEDq = 14'b11111100011001;
            4'b1111： LEDq = 14'b11111100010010;
            default: LEDq = 14'b01111110111111;
        endcase
    end
    
    always @*
    begin
        case (G)
            4'b0000： LEDg = 14'b11111111000000;
            4'b0001： LEDg = 14'b11111111111001;
            4'b0010： LEDg = 14'b11111110100100;
            4'b0011： LEDg = 14'b11111110110000;
            4'b0100： LEDg = 14'b11111110011001;
            4'b0101： LEDg = 14'b11111110010010;
            4'b0110： LEDg = 14'b11111110000010;
            4'b0111： LEDg = 14'b11111111111000;
            4'b1000： LEDg = 14'b11111110000000;
            4'b1001： LEDg = 14'b11111110010000;
            4'b1010： LEDg = 14'b11111101000000;
            4'b1011： LEDg = 14'b11111101111001;
            4'b1100： LEDg = 14'b11111100100100;
            4'b1101： LEDg = 14'b11111100110000;
            4'b1110： LEDg = 14'b11111100011001;
            4'b1111： LEDg = 14'b11111100010010;
            default: LEDg = 14'b01111110111111;
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

The errors are:

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at display.v(8) near text ï

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at display.v(8) near text "ï";  expecting ":", or ","

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at display.v(8) near text ¼

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at display.v(8) near text š

May I know how should I correct it? I had searched through Internet but find no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When I copied your code and executed it in my software I noticed that you don't have colons (`:`) in your code only [fullwidth colons](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff1a/index.htm) (`：`). Changing this weird unicode colons to ascii colons almost solved all problems. You use also undefined `G`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the error to me. May I know what/how this error can happen? Because my friends seem like don have this problem with their code, I am guessing it is because of the PC?  Then, could you give me some hints or solution how should I fix this? Much appreciated!

Comment: I guess that you have to change your keyboard language in operating system settings. If you are using windows 10 this may help. 

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-the-input-and-display-language-settings-in-windows-10-12a10cb4-8626-9b77-0ccb-5013e0c7c7a2